# Simplify the expression with matrices

Tags: linear-algebra

I have some doubt, for resolving this. Let A,B,C be matrices, $$A=\dfrac{1}{2}(AC^{-T}+BC^{-T})^{T}\dfrac{1}{2}(AC^{-T}+BC^{-T})$$
$$=\dfrac{1}{4}((AC^{-T})^{T}+(BC^{-T})^{T})(AC^{-T}+BC^{T})$$
$$=\dfrac{1}{4}(CA^{T}+CB^{T})(AC^{-T}+BC^{-T})$$
$$\therefore 4A=CA^{T}AC^{-T}+CA^{T}BC^{-T}+CB^{T}AC^{-T}+CB^{T}BC^{-T}$$

And, I don't know how to continue. Any help please!

Comment: Are you asking for a clarification of what has happened already or are you looking for a simpler form at the end?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks good so far.

$$4C^{-1}AC^T = A^TA +A^TB + B^TA + B^TB = A^T(A+B) + B^T(A + B) = (A^T+B^T)(A+B)$$

Comment: I think you mean to say $4A=C(A^TA+A^TB+\dots+B^TB)C^{-T}$, which is different than saying $4CAC^{-T}=A^TA+\dots+B^TB$

Comment: @JMoravitz yes thanks, should be correct now

Comment: you seem to be assuming that $C$ is invertible, which might not necessarily be the case.  Perhaps $C$ is rectangular.  Perhaps $C$ is square yet singular.  Multiplying by the inverse of a matrix which you don't know to be invertible is the same error as dividing by zero.

Comment: I'm not familiar with this notion but I assumed that  $C^{-T} = (C^{-1})^{T}$ this makes no sense other wise, as the inverse operation of transposition is again transposition. @JMoravitz

Comment: #I'm not that stupid